# How to declare member functions in javascript? Getting "TypeError: Object.function is not a function"

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm coming from a java background and I'm trying to declare members in a java style way. Why are my functions not visible to the outside or not recognized as functions? What is the correct way to declare memberfunctions for a function from within the function?

```
function Animation() {
  var draw = function draw() {
      ...
  };

  var move = function move() {
    ...
  };
}

function startAnimation() {
  ...
  var animation = new Animation();
  function frame() {
    ...
    animation.move()
    animation.draw();
    ...
  }
}
```

When executing the code I just get an error in the console:

```
TypeError: Object.function is not a function
```

Comment: You're declaring local variables, visible only inside the `Animation()` function. You want member variables, e.g. `this.draw = function draw() { ... };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like this to work as an instance method, you can also do

```
function Animation() {...}

Animation.prototype.move = function() {...};

Animation.prototype.draw = function() {...};
```

or with ES6

```
class Animation {

    constructor() {...}

    move() {
       ...
    }

    draw() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your code, `draw` & `move` are *private* variables.

Assign your functions to members of `this`:

```
function Animation() {
  this.draw = function() {
      ...
  };

  this.move = function() {
    ...
  };
}

var an1 = new Animation();
an1.draw() // do something
an1.move() // also do something
```

Of course you are also able to assign it to the prototype as *@UnicodeSnowman* describe.

Comment: _local_ not _private_. There is a distinction to be made here, considering object constructors in JavaScript are just functions, and there is no true notion of OOP privacy in the language.

Comment: @Oka it also can be as a local & as a private, JS doesnt support private variables, but according to the Douglas Crockford it can be implemented in this way too. Please look at [this](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html). You are also right

Answer (score 3):

animation is a function not an object try this

```
var Animation = {
    draw: function() {
     ...
    },

    move: function() {
     ...
    },
}
```

ofcourse now to call it just do Animation.draw()

or if you want to go prototype wich wasnt in the question

```
var Animation = (function ()
    var Class = function()
    {
       this.draw = function () {};
       this.move = function () {};
    });
    (Class.prototype);
    return Class;
})();
```

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: @Oleander Given this answer, how would you create multiple instances of `Animation`? With the original code, and the other answers, that's possible.

Comment: @PaulRoub Aha, missed that part. This is why downvoters should leave a comment. I mean, we're still here to learn.

Comment: well, you could technically use `Object.create`

Comment: your brackets in the second example are wrong I think.